# Scala type mismatch; found : Int(0) required: Int

Tags: scala

I have written below wrapper class for `Int`.

```
    case class Wrapper[Int](value: Int) {
        def map(f: Int => Int): Wrapper[Int] = Wrapper(f(value))
        def flatMap(f: Int => Wrapper[Int]): Wrapper[Int] = f(value)
        def filter(f: Int => Boolean): Wrapper[Int] = Wrapper(if(f(value)) 0 else value)
    }
```

When I compile the code I get below error -

```
    type mismatch; 
    [error]  found   : Int(0)
    [error]  required: Int
    [error]     def filter(f: Int => Boolean): Wrapper[Int] = Wrapper(if (f(value)) 0 else value)
    [error]                                                                         ^
    [error] one error found
```

I couldn't find any obvious reason for this error. Any Idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By writing `class Wrapper[Int]`, you've defined a type parameter named `Int`. Whenever you write `Int` inside the class, you refer to that type parameter, not to the actual `Int` type.

Your definition is completely equivalent to this:

```
case class Wrapper[T](value: T) {
    def map(f: T => T): Wrapper[T] = Wrapper(f(value))
    def flatMap(f: T => Wrapper[T]): Wrapper[T] = f(value)
    def filter(f: T => Boolean): Wrapper[T] = Wrapper(if(f(value)) 0 else value)
}
```

And if you try to compile this version, you'll get the more understandable error that there was an `Int` where a `T` was expected.

If you want your wrapper to be specific to integers, you should remove the type parameter.

Comment: The improved advice is to compile with `-Xlint`, which would add: `warning: type parameter Int defined in class Wrapper shadows class Int defined in package scala. You may want to rename your type parameter, or possibly remove it.`